# GraphQL Documentation Explorer not showing in browser .net core 3.1

Tags: graphql, .net-core-3.1

i am new to GraphQL, i have build a sample project using GraphQL which is working fine, but **'Documentation Explore'** (my custom schema) not loaded in Browser .net core 3.1 also attached **StartUp.cs**.
note : Which was works in .net core 2.0.

**here is startup.cs**

```
using GraphiQl;
using GraphQL;
using GraphQL.Server;
using GraphQL.Types;
{
    public class Startup
    {

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
            });

            services.AddSingleton<IDependencyResolver>(c => new FuncDependencyResolver(type => c.GetRequiredService(type)));

            services.AddDbContext<RealEstateContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:RealEstateDb"]));
            services.AddScoped<IDocumentExecuter, DocumentExecuter>();
            services.AddScoped<PropertyQuery>();
            services.AddScoped<PropertyMutation>();
            services.AddScoped<PropertyType>();
            services.AddScoped<ConstituencyType>();
            services.AddScoped<PropertyInputType>();
            services.AddScoped<PaymentType>();
                    services.AddGraphQL(options =>
            {
                options.EnableMetrics = true;
                options.ExposeExceptions = true;
            }).AddWebSockets();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env,RealEstateContext db)
        {
            app.UseWebSockets();
            app.UseGraphQLWebSockets<RealEstateSchema>("/graphql");
            app.UseGraphQL<RealEstateSchema>("/graphql");
            db.EnsureSeedData();
        }

    }
}
```

[Here is for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxj3O.png)

Answer (score 3):

Do your query results start with "data"? If not then this may be the problem. The Documentation Explorer (it's a React app) expects the results of its metadata query to start with "data".

I added it with the following code in the `GraphQLController` and then the documentation appeared.

```js
[Route("/graphql")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] GraphQLQueryDTO query)
{
    var result = await _executer.ExecuteAsync(_ =>
    {
        _.Schema = _schema;
        _.Query = query.Query;
        _.Inputs = query.Variables?.ToInputs();

    });

    if (result.Errors?.Count > 0) {
        return BadRequest(result.Errors[0].ToString());
    }

    // The response json is not starting with "data" - maybe to look prettier
    // This issue with this is that when GraphiQL requests the schema, GraphiQL
    // is expecting a response that starts "data". So I am adding "data" to the
    // front of the response if this is a schema request.  
    if (typeof(Dictionary<string, object>).IsInstanceOfType(result.Data)) {
        var dictData = (Dictionary<string, object>)result.Data;
        if (dictData.ContainsKey("__schema")) {
            var result2 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            result2.Add("data", dictData);
            return Ok(result2);
        } else { 
            return Ok(result.Data);
        }
    }
    return Ok(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue (Schema and Docs was not loading on Playground) despite following all the suggestions on Stack Overflow and Github.

It is solved when I assigned the `Query` property of `Schema` following;

Before:

```
public class ApiSchema : Schema, ISchema
{
    public ApiSchema(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) : base(serviceProvider)
    {
        Mutation = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApiMutation>();
    }
}
```

After:

```
public class ApiSchema : Schema, ISchema
{
    public ApiSchema(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) : base(serviceProvider)
    {
        Query = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApiQuery>();
        Mutation = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApiMutation>();
    }
}
```

This is my Startup.cs file:

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
                .AddNewtonsoftJson();
            services.AddOptions();

            services.AddScoped<TestInputType>();
            services.AddScoped<TestType>();
            services.AddScoped<ApiMutation>();
            services.AddScoped<ApiSchema>();
            services.AddGraphQL()
                .AddErrorInfoProvider(options => options.ExposeExceptionStackTrace =true)
                .AddNewtonsoftJson()
                .AddDataLoader()
                .AddGraphTypes(ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
            services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
            });
        }
        
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseGraphQL<ApiSchema>();
            app.UseWebSockets();
            app.UseGraphQLPlayground(new PlaygroundOptions());


            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapGraphQLPlayground();
            });

        }
    }
```

And this is my .csproj file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL.Server.Transports.AspNetCore.NewtonsoftJson" Version="5.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL.Server.Ui.Playground" Version="5.0.2" />
    
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.1.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="....csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```