# "No schema available" Graphiql .net core api

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, graphql, graphiql

I'm trying to develop a simple graphql api in .net core.
When I run the application, I don't see any schema in the document explorer.

Everything seems to be right. I could not find the problem.

.net core version 3.1

graphql version 3.2

GraphiQl version 2.0

[retunr page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FHnq.png)

code part as below

Model

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Type

```
public class CustomerType : ObjectGraphType<Customer>
{
    public CustomerType()
    {
        Field(x => x.Id);
        Field(x => x.Name);
    }
}
```

Query

```
public class GraphQuery : ObjectGraphType
{
    public GraphQuery()
    {
        Field<ListGraphType<CustomerType>>(
           "customers",
           resolve: context =>
           {
               return new List<Customer>
               {
                   new Customer
                   {
                       Id=1,
                       Name="Faruk"
                   }
                };
           });
    }
}
```

Schema

```
public class GraphSchema : Schema
{
    public GraphSchema(IServiceProvider provider)
        : base(provider)
    {
        Query = provider.GetRequiredService<GraphQuery>();
    }
}
```

Controller

```
namespace GqlDemo2.Api.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("graphql")]
    public class GraphqlController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly IDocumentExecuter _documentExecuter;
        private readonly ISchema _schema;

        public GraphqlController(ISchema schema, IDocumentExecuter documentExecuter)
        {
            _schema = schema;
            _documentExecuter = documentExecuter;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> PostAsync([FromBody] GraphQLQuery query)
        {
            if (query == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(query)); }
            var inputs = query.Variables.ToInputs();
            var executionOptions = new ExecutionOptions
            {
                Schema = _schema,
                Query = query.Query,
                Inputs = inputs
            };

            var result = await _documentExecuter.ExecuteAsync(executionOptions).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (result.Errors?.Count > 0)
            {
                return BadRequest(result);
            }

            return Ok(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Startup

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddSingleton<IDocumentExecuter, DocumentExecuter>();
            services.AddSingleton<CustomerType>();
            services.AddSingleton<GraphQuery>();
            var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            services.AddSingleton<ISchema>(new GraphSchema(new FuncServiceProvider(type => sp.GetService(type))));

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseGraphiQl("/graphiql");
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Solved 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61224442/graphql-documentation-explorer-not-showing-in-browser-net-core-3-1

Answer (score -1):

clear your browser cache and cookies because that solve mine

Comment: It's not a problem with the browser cache and cookies. I tried in private window but nothing changed